# Spring-data-jpa dependency is not working

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, spring-data-jpa, dependencies, spring-tool-suite

I am adding spring-data-jpa dependency in my pom.xml . even though i am unable to to use javax.presistence.* this package which will helps in creating entity,table like that . i have done updates mulitple times the project also deleted and readded the depency i had gone through lot of online pages but i dont get the exact resolution for this issue.
adding the pom.xml of my project
Thanks in advance

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.dailycodelearner</groupId>
    <artifactId>TaskManagementApplication</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>TaskManagementApplication</name>
    <description>creating a task management application which is safe and secured where user can login, register and one user can&apos;t see the task lists of other users without jwt tokens and each user can generate unique tokens </description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

i am unable to use javax.presistence.* package classes

Comment: Any build error in "Problems" tab?

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand correctly, your problem is actually with `java.persistence` and not spring-data-jpa.

This is because you’re using Java version 17 and the later Java versions no longer support javax. You need to use the `jakarta.persistence` dependency in its place.